# Slack API: `groups.list` not returning private channels I am part of

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to get a list of all channels (public and private) to which I can post messages.

I am getting a list of public channels using `channels.list` and it is working well. It is returning me all the public channels to which I can post.

I am trying to get a list of private channels by using [`groups.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.list). The call is returning an OK response, but I am not getting any results.

I have created a private channel. I am the only member. This channel is not being returned by the `group.list` API call.

I have `groups:read` and `channels:read` oauth scopes.

This is being done using the `Slacker` python library.

Even the following `curl` call does not return me any private channels:

```
 curl --data "token=xoxb-REDACTED"  'https://slack.com/api/groups.list'
```

How can I get a list of private channels I am part of using the Slack API?

UPDATE:

If I use the dev token in the above `curl` call, it does correctly return me my private channels.

When I look inside of Slack at the integrations, I see the integration with my dev app. It says that the dev app can `Access information about user’s private channels, granted by 1 team member` (among others). Something is amiss and I don't know where. It seems that the oauth token has an issue, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that I was also requesting the `bot` oauth scope. When Slack finished authorizing my app, it was issuing a personal token and a bot token. The bot token does not have access to the private channels, while the personal one does.